# Save PDF-file to XML-file using php

Tags: php, xml, pdf

I have a form in which you can upload an image, which I then save to a folder on the server using php.
I'm storing the other data entered into the form in an xml-file, also using php. I now want to be able to store the pdf-file/the pdf-data in this xml-file as well for later use (the form acts as a template and I later want to store the entire information in another file and display it to the user).
I read about Base64 encoding etc. but I'm not sure if that applies to PDF-files as well because all I could find was how to do that for images or if there's an easier way to do it for my case?

Edit: Here's the HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="profile.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="hidden" name="create_xml" value="true">

    <label for="name">Name: </label><br>
    <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <label for="email">E-mail: </label><br> 
    <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <label for="textbox">Write something: </label><br>
    <textarea name="textbox" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea><br>
    <label for="fileToUpload">Upload a PDF-file: </label>
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="file-select">
    <input type="text" name="filename" placeholder="Enter the name of your file"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

php that saves the data to the xml file:

```
if(isset($_POST['create_xml'])) {

    $xml = new DOMDocument();

    $newProfile = $xml->createElement('Profile');
    $xml->appendChild($newProfile);

    $name = $xml->createElement('Name', $name);
    $newProfile->appendChild($name);

    $email = $xml->createElement('EMail', $emailaddress);
    $newProfile->appendChild($email);

    $textbox = $xml->createElement('Text', $text);
    $newProfile->appendChild($textbox);

    $xml->formatOutput = true;
    $xml->saveXML();
    $xml->save($filename.".xml");

}
```

Comment: save only pdf link(which is encoded by php) to xml

Comment: How would I do that exactly? And thank you very much for your fast reply!

Comment: show your code where you added the form data to xml

Comment: @AnandPandey I just entered it in my initial question above. Let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: Well, you have to upload the pdf in any folder and after that the uploaded link will save to the xml. Are you understand?

Comment: I already uploaded the file to a folder (I didn't insert that part of my code), but I don't quite understand how to save the link to xml or how to reference the path in xml. Could you explain that?

Comment: Give me 5 min i give you the answer

Comment: One more question you want to make xml at insertion time or after the click to any other button?

Comment: I would like to make the xml once you click on the submit button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make xml at the time of insert data in DB:

```
if($this->input->post('submit')){   
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $filename = $_POST['filename'];
    $year = gmdate("Y");

    if($_FILES){
        $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] = $files['fileToUpload']['name'];
        $_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'] = $files['fileToUpload']['type'];
        $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'] = $files['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
        $_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] = $files['fileToUpload']['error'];
        $_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'] = $files['fileToUpload']['size'];
        $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $mtime = uniqid(microtime());
        $uniqueid = substr($mtime, 2, 8);
        $pdfname = $uniqueid . '.' . $ext; // pdf file encrypt name here which need to save
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $pdfname);
    }

    //Your insert query here remember here you should add $pdfname as pdflink 


    // If successful insertion than 
    $xml = new DOMDocument();

    $newProfile = $xml->createElement('Profile');
    $xml->appendChild($newProfile);

    $name = $xml->createElement('Name', $name);
    $newProfile->appendChild($name);

    $email = $xml->createElement('EMail', $email);
    $newProfile->appendChild($email);

    $textbox = $xml->createElement('Text', $filename);
    $newProfile->appendChild($textbox);

    $pdflink = $xml->createElement('Text', $pdfname);
    $newProfile->appendChild($pdflink);

    $xml->formatOutput = true;
    $xml->saveXML();
    $xml->save($filename.".xml");
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! I'll try to implement that right away

Comment: @A.S.J: I have edited the ansswer plz check this and let me know.

Comment: Could you explain this part please: $mtime = uniqid(microtime());
        $uniqueid = substr($mtime, 2, 8);
        $pdfname = $uniqueid . '.' . $ext; // pdf file encrypt name here which need to sav ?

Comment: This is only use for uniqueness means each time when you submit the form the file has uniquename and you want to save only the $pdfname

Comment: oh I see, thank you ! I hope this is not off-topic, but I just tested it and I received something along the lines of <Text>3456253.pdf</Text>. How can I convert that back if I want to use it in another HTML-file?

Comment: Well i am not using encryption here if you want to encrypt than add base64_encode($pdfname); and for decode base64_decode($pdfname);

Comment: I was just wondering about how I could use that if I wanted to display it in another HTML-file (like, how would I reference it)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158682/discussion-between-anand-pandey-and-a-s-j).